# Checkbox auto submit

Tags: html, form-submit

I try to make a friendly user interface for admins on my project but I'm facing some troubles when it comes to display all tasks. Basically I retrive the data from db then I put them in table and here comes the issue. For each task I have a status, a binary value in db. I wanna display that status in a table column represented by a checkbox, `checked for 1`  `unchecked for 0`. But I dont know how to make it dinamic, i mean if its already checked and I press the button to submit 0 in db and vice versa. Its possible to submit those values without a button?!?  Could somebody give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Add js triggers: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp and look for jquery or native realizations

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" onchange="bar(this)">
<script>
    function bar(element) {
        // send ajax request to update your db
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Its possible just to submit the checkbox and then to update the data from my controller function?

Comment: @TerchilăMarian you mean with page reloading?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: @TerchilăMarian then add code to submit your form https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp, anyway you should use javascript